# R apriori() not showing expected output

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I run the apriori function in R using this sample dataset.

```
Bread   Milk    
Bread   Diapers Beer    Eggs
Milk    Diapers Beer    Cola
Bread   Milk    Diapers Beer
Bread   Milk    Diapers Cola
```

As I can see here,  the support for rule {Milk,Diaper} -> {Beer} is 0.4 (2/5 ) and the confidence is 2/3 0.67.

But when I run the following command, the output I get is not showing the rule {Milk,Diaper} -> {Beer}.

```
rules <- apriori(a, parameter = list(supp = 0.3, conf = 0.6))
```

The output I got is below. Here no where I see the expected rule. Also I see the  basket items along with V1,V2 which are the column names of the data frame.

Please see what's wrong here.

```
> inspect(rules)
   lhs             rhs          support confidence lift
   1  {}           => {V2=Milk}        0.6       0.60  1.0
   2  {}           => {V1=Bread}       0.8       0.80  1.0
   3  {V2=Diapers} => {V3=Beer}        0.4       1.00  2.5
   4  {V3=Beer}    => {V2=Diapers}     0.4       1.00  2.5
   5  {V3=Diapers} => {V2=Milk}        0.4       1.00  1.7
   6  {V2=Milk}    => {V3=Diapers}     0.4       0.67  1.7
   7  {V3=Diapers} => {V1=Bread}       0.4       1.00  1.2
   8  {V2=Milk}    => {V1=Bread}       0.6       1.00  1.2
   9  {V1=Bread}   => {V2=Milk}        0.6       0.75  1.2
   10 {V2=Milk,                                           
       V3=Diapers} => {V1=Bread}       0.4       1.00  1.2
   11 {V1=Bread,                                          
       V3=Diapers} => {V2=Milk}        0.4       1.00  1.7
   12 {V1=Bread,                                          
       V2=Milk}    => {V3=Diapers}     0.4       0.67  1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

apriori() takes a transaction as input. As my input is a dataframe, I got the V1, V2 and apriori seem to be doing column position based matching.

When you have a data frame in the form of basket convert it into a transaction with

```
trans = read.transactions("data/rules_samp.csv", format = "basket", sep=",");
```